# rvm `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)

Tags: ruby

run a ruby code got error "rvm `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)"

```
bash-3.2$ rvm --default ruby-2.0.0-p451

-bash-3.2$ rvm list  

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.0.0-p451 [ x86_64 ]

-bash-3.2$ gem list --local        

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.5.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
executable-hooks (1.3.1)
gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
minitest (4.3.2)
net-ssh (2.9.1)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)

-bash-3.2$ gem list --local rubygems

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

rubygems-bundler (1.4.2)
```

to run the script:

```
ruby test.rb
`require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
```

$ cat test.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH.start(.............
```

what's going on? please advice. thanks

Comment: The version Ruby you are using there you no need to do `require rubygems`.. But still *error not expected*.

Comment: Can you run this way `ruby -v test.rb` I want to see, which version of Ruby interpreter is being called.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, you are right it's using ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [x86_64-linux] not the default ruby-2.0.0-p451, how to use ruby-2.0.0-p451? thanks